# django context_processors, request 'function' object has no attribute 'path'

Tags: django, request

First question asked in stack overflow here.

So, I am starting a few Django projects and ended up with this issue:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'path'
```

Which happens on the following context processor:

```
def get_request_promotions(request):

   promotions = PagePromotion._default_manager.select_related() \
       .prefetch_related('content_object') \
       .filter(page_url=request.path) \
       .order_by('display_order')

   if 'q' in request.GET:
       keyword_promotions \
        = KeywordPromotion._default_manager.select_related()\
        .filter(keyword=request.GET['q'])
   if keyword_promotions.exists():
       promotions = list(chain(promotions, keyword_promotions))
   return render(promotions, request)
```

That is, Django isn't able to find the path object on request. This is my context processors in `settings.py`:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'), ],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',  # For EL-pagination
            'common.core.context_processors.metadata',
            'portfolio.search.context_processors.search_form',
            'store.promotions.context_processors.promotions',
            'store.checkout.context_processors.checkout',
            'common.accounts.notifications.context_processors.notifications',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Any hints?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you post the complete stacktrace?

Comment: There seen to be a few things wrong here. But are you sure that's a context processor? It's not listed in your settings, and a context processor is supposed to return a dict, not render a template.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! It was really the render method that wasn't right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, to all who might be interested in this question, the problem was with the 'render' method. Technically, a function based view must return a HttpResponse object, and render just does not do that.

I've changed the last code line to

```py
return render_to_response(promotions, request)
```

and it worked like a charm.